# Commander.js throwing error when trying to pass a string to a required field

Tags: javascript, typescript, command-line-interface, node-commander

I'm just trying to pass a value as a string as a required field

```
import commander from 'commander';

const split = (str: string) => {
    return str.split(',')
};

export const cli = () => {
    commander
        .version('0.0.1')
        .option('-q --query <value>', `Add query example: -q #javascript`, '#javascript')
        .option('-s --min [n]', `Add min amount of time to wait before each action example: -s 2500`, 2500)
        .option('-l --max [n]', `Add max amount of time to wait before each action example: -l 240000`, 240000)
        .option('-d --duration [n]', `Duration in hours example: -d 24`, 1)
        .option('-a --actions <list>', `Actions to use example: -a like, follow`, split, [])
        .parse(process.argv)
        .on('error', () => {
            commander.outputHelp();
            process.exit();
        });

    return commander;
}
```

I'm running

```
 $ ts-node ./index.ts -q #java -s 2403 -l 240001 -d 2 -a follow,like

 /* 
    starting tweety bot 
    error: option `-q --query <value>' argument missing
 */
```

I'm providing the value but still throws. If i change to non required fields it just returns the defaultValue rather than passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you need to add quotes I had omitted after the array didn't work with quotes.

`ts-node ./index.ts -q '#java' -s 2403 -l 240001 -d 2 -a follow,like`

Comment: Without the quotes, the hash is interpreted as the shell comment character and the rest of the line is ignored.

Comment: interesting it just threw me off when i added quotes around the array that i split on , it doesnt pick it up but i guess thats because its taking that as the first item.  cheers the the explanation!